# $.getJSON - unable to catch response when using parameters in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I have been struggling since yesterday with the following piece of code.

```
function findLocation(){

  alert(1);

  $.getJSON( "http://www.omc4web.com/geoip/geoip.php", 
    {ip: "127.0.0.1",
    callingurl: "www.thissite.com" }, 
    function( result ){
      alert(2);
      $.each(result, function(i, field)
      {
        alert(i); 
        if(i=="country")
        { 
          country_code = field;
        }

      });
    })

}
```

It does not seem to want to get beyond the calling of the php script. The returned data is  `{"country":"US","store":"US"}` but the function does not seem to want to process it and I never get to alert(2). I have placed monitors in the php script and I can see that it does indeed get called with the correct parameters and it does return the data expected.

if you call http://www.omc4web.com/geoip/geoip.php?ip=127.0.0.1&callingurl=www.thissite.com from your browser you will see that data is returned.

The same piece of code calling a URL with no parameters behaves correctly, but not with the above setup.

My few remaining hairs would appreciate some help on this.

additional info:

- header('Content-type: application/json'); set on php script
- tried it on chrome and firefox
- no errors show up on firebug just a blank response screen
- running script from localhost, but if its a cross domain issue, why am I able to make a similar call (without params) to amazon? `$.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/",function(result){` works fine as does the popular flickr example.
- I am using `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Thanks in advance

Ossi

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: If you go to the link you've posted, that's nice and valid JSON, but it's not JSONP, so unless the getJSON call is also made from the same domain, this won't work unless you change the serverside script to output valid JSONP, including the callback.

Comment: Do you get something like _Origin <website name> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin_ in the error console?

Comment: There was absolutely nothing that I could see Salman. But using jsonp did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a cross domain issue. I guess you're able to use `freegeoip.net` because you're using **JSONP**. Try looking at the jQuery documentation to learn how to use JSONP: [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: JSONP was the way to go. Implemented a callback function and the world is a happy place again. Thanks a lot guys for your help.